# Frozen windshield wiper fluid on road trip

Tags: maintenance, windshield-wipers, windshield, windshield-washer, ice

We are driving in a winter storm and our old wiper fluid is frozen. We picked up some de-icer fluid from a gas station but it has not yet unfrozen the fluid.

Any suggestions for an on the road fix?

The engine doesn't seem to be heating up the frozen fluid and the windshield wipers keep smearing anything on the windshield.

Comment: That's a tough one. You'd need to heat up the reservoir somehow and get the old fluid out, then put non-freezing type in. Not good at all. I wish I had a *real* answer for you here.

Comment: Pack a bunch of the hand warmer packs around it?

Comment: Do you have any tools?  If you had a good amount of room left in the windshield wiper reservoir you could pour coolant into it to unfreeze the concoction and then pull the tube off the bottom of the reservoir once it's melted to drain it.  Flush with bottled water.  Put the hose back on.  Fill with nonfreezing wiper fluid.....just a thought

Comment: What make/model/year of car.  I'll look it up and see if I can think of other things.

Comment: @DucatiKiller volvo s40 year 2000

Comment: @FredWilson - That's a great suggestion.

Comment: Will update if the posted solution works!

Comment: Best of luck to you.

Comment: @DucatiKiller  Ok McGiver <sic>  lol   let's see what happens.  $1 says it's works    :-)

Comment: Did you find a trick to solve your problem while you were on the road?

Comment: Unfortunately not.  A night in a heated garage was necessary to clear the lines: boiling water, -25f fluid did not help, and I was in no position to make use of your fine blow up diagram (the pump is quite inaccessible.). Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 6):

Here's a parts explosion

[image]

The hose #9 you could drain through.

I like the coolant idea.

pour coolant in the reservoir, it might take a bit but it will turn the slush into liquid.  There a glycerin in it and it's alcohol based so it's miscible with any alcohol in your wiper fluid.  Nothing bad will happen.

***Others chime in if this is ridiculous to you for some reason***

Once its liquid, pull the hose #9 off the off the bottom of the tank and drain it.  I can't tell from here but if the little pump is there you would need to operate it from the cabin to get the tank empty.

Once empty rinse it out good with bottle water.

reattach hose and then fill it up with non-freezing washer fluid from the convenience store.

Hope this helps!